# model disappears in object mode

Tags: edit-mode, object-mode

[image]

I have applied modifiers and my hat vanished in object mode. how can i get it back?

Comment: select the cylinder in the outliner and press `NumPad .` dot key

Comment: nothing happened its till the same...

Comment: what modifier did u apply? just undo so it will reverse the modifier u applied.

Comment: Subsurface division... every time i apply this modifier there is issue.... now i see i went to sculpt tab and the hat isn't there.. but it is visible in texture tab...

Comment: I got it... accidentally unchecked the tv icon by subsurface modifier and everything is fine....

Comment: Anyways thanks aloot....